# Extract leading number from string

Tags: mysql, function

I need to make a conversion to a parameter, in a MySQL function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunction (X VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
DECLARE X1 INT;
SET X1 = [...]
END;
```

X is something like "10%", and I need to extract "10" as a number (X is a number in percents, but represented as a VARCHAR parameter). So, in this case, X1 must be 10. I don't know what I have to write in place of [...]

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
SET X1 = CAST(REPLACE(X, '%', '') AS UNSIGNED)
```